# OPENROWSET - Operating system error code 5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)

Tags: sql, openrowset

OK I know there is a lot of questions and answers regarding this issue, however, they only seem to be for permissions only. This may be different because of the **failed to retrieve text for this error** at the end of the error.

The statement

```
SELECT BulkColumn  FROM Openrowset(Bulk 'E:\wf', Single_Blob) ImageData
```

Reason why I don't think this is a permission problem is because

- I run this command from the same machine that the file is located
- I have enabled BULKADMIN for the SQL user

The only thought that could go against my belief is that I get the same error when I login with Windows Authentication.

I am a bit unclear about giving SQL logins access to the file system, that may be the issue.

Any help would be good

Thanks